# Revit 2022 Application Idling Event not firing

Tags: vb.net, revit-api

I have troubles in Revit API 2022. The Idling Event won't fire when a structural framework instance is selected.

To be more specific, this mysterious error only occurs when a document is updated from a previous revit version to 2022 and the element (structural framework) is already drawn in the document. Any other element category works and if I copy the structural framework or draw a new one it will work too.

My question is, is this a known problem? Is there any workaround or another workflow to get the changed selection?

```
AddHandler application.Idling, AddressOf application_Idling

'When structural framework is selected it won't fire anymore, if deselected then it will work again
Private Sub application_Idling(sender As Object, e As Autodesk.Revit.UI.Events.IdlingEventArgs)
    If uiApplication Is Nothing Then
        Return
    End If

    Dim selected As List(Of ElementId) = uiApplication.ActiveUIDocument.Selection.GetElementIds
    'Do Something

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Idling` event does not fire on selection. You can [subscribe to the Idling event to be notified when Revit is not in an active tool or transaction](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2023/e233027b-ba8c-0bd1-37b7-93a066efa5a3.htm).

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thanks for the answer, afaik the idling event fires before and also after I select an element and do nothing with that. So if I select an element I wont get a notification but after that, doing nothing, it should fire again and I can get the selected element. But only when I select the structural framework it wont fire again after selection. On an other element like a wall, floor, roof, door, or anything else it fires again after selection.
by the way sorry for my bad english, I hope its's written clearly.

Comment: Wow. Interesting. Unexpected, undocumented, unsupported, I'm afraid. Sounds pretty useful, in the cases when it does work. Can't you use something official, such as the [SelectionChanged Event](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2023/81ada6e8-47f1-4ff6-fcb8-907e0a389c7c.htm)?